# Crear un dataframe a partir de una columna que deseo modificar, añadir otra columna y una tercera que las compare en R

Tags: r, dataframe

Sea:

```
set.seed(2020)
y_fitted<-runif(10,min=0,max = 1)
y_fitted
0.197 0.078 0.818 0.942 0.884 0.166 0.355 0.748 0.451 0.556

y<-sample(0:1,10,replace=T)
y
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

Quiero crear un dataframe tal que:

- Columna 1: si `y_fitted>= 0.5` sea 1 y si `y_fitted<0.5` sea 0
- Columna 2: `y` sin modificar
- Columna 3: `TRUE` si `y_fitted==y` ; `FALSE` si `y_fitted!==y`

Finalmente, obtener el porcentaje de valores `TRUE` que hay en la tercera columna.

**El problema lo estoy teniendo al crear la columna 1**:
No entiendo porqué al ejecutar las siguientes líneas de código, los valores se modifican por 1 tal y como deseo, pero los valores entre `0:0.4999` **no se cambian a 0**.

```
y_fitted[y_fitted==0:0.499999999]<-0
y_fitted[y_fitted==0.5:1]<-1
```

Todo esto lo quiero hacer para **analizar la bondad del ajuste** de mi modelo logit binomial, donde `y_fitted`son los valores que estima mi modelo y los valores de `y` son los valores de mi variable a explicar (endógena).

Pongo `0.499999999` para asegurarme de que **ningún valor se queda fuera del cambio** que deseo efectuar en la columna 1, pero estoy seguro de que hay alguna forma más limpia de hacerlo.

El porcentaje que pido me indicaría, entonces, el porcentaje de aciertos que tiene mi modelo dentro de la muestra con la que estoy trabajando.

¿Cuál es la forma más eficiente de realizar esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta clausula: `y_fitted[y_fitted==0:0.499999999]<-0` (y la siguiente también) no tienen el sentido que buscas darle, algunas razones que puedo decirte:

- `0:0.499999999` entiendo que lo que buscas es generar una secuencia de valores de 0 a 0.49..., sin embargo, los `:` funciona como una secuencia de paso 1, no funciona para una secuencia con un paso menor, por esto el resultado será un vector con un único valor 0, puedes verificarlo evaluando `0:0.49999`.
- Para generar secuencias NO enteras hay que usar `seq()`, sin embargo, aunque generases esta secuencia así `seq(from=0, to=0.49, by=.1)`, siempre será un conjunto de valores discretos, podrás agregar más valores aumentando la precisión/paso con `by` pero siempre será un vector de valores discretos.
- Además cuando comparas el `a == b` lo que ocurre es que comparas cada valor de `a` con cada valor de `b` es decir algo así `a[1] == b[1], a[2] == b[2]` y así, incluyendo reciclado de valores si un vector es mayor que el otro, lo cual sin duda no resuelve el problema.

Lo que buscas, en realidad debieras escribirlo así:

```
y_fitted[y_fitted < 0.5] <- 0
y_fitted[y_fitted >= 0.5] <-1
```

O mucho más conciso:

```
y_fitted <- ifelse(y_fitted >= 0.5, 1, 0)
```

O por que no, aprovechando la conversión de lógicos a enteros, esto, gracias a que quieres los valores 1 y 0 que son consistentes con el `TRUE` o `FALSE`:

```
y_fitted <- as.integer(y_fitted >= 0.5)
```